# Why $\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, ideals, solvable-groups

We have defined the derived series $\{\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}\}$ inductively by
$$\mathscr{D}^1\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}],\ \mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}=[\mathscr{D}^{k-1}\mathfrak{g},\mathscr{D}^{k-1}\mathfrak{g}].$$
Now I hope to prove that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}]=\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}$, then $\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$. It is easy for me to show that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathscr{D}^1\mathfrak{g}]=\mathscr{D}^1\mathfrak{g}$, and that is equivalently $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$. And then? I find it difficult to prove this question by induction. Or are there any other ways to prove it?

I'm a novice in learning Lie algebras and this question may seem quite easy for you. I'd be extremely grateful if you can give me more details to help me!

Comment: Asserting that $\mathscr D^k\mathfrak g$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak g$ means that $[\mathfrak{g},\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}]\subset\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}$, rather than $[\mathfrak{g},\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}]=\mathscr{D}^k\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Use the Jacobi identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$, then $[\mathfrak{g},D\mathfrak{h}]\subset [\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]]$ by the Jacobi identity, which is contained in $[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]=\mathfrak{h}$ since $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal. So $D\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal as well.

It follows by induction on $k$ that $D^k\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal. This applies in particular to $\mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: I'm still confused. In my opinion, the Jacobi identity is:$${\displaystyle [X,[Y,Z]]+[Y,[Z,X]]+[Z,[X,Y]]\ =\ 0}.$$ But I can conclude $[\mathfrak{g},D\mathfrak{h}]\subset [\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]]$ by $$[\mathfrak{g},D\mathfrak{h}]=[\mathfrak{g},[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]]=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]=\mathfrak{h}$$ and $$[\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]]=[\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]]=[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]=\mathfrak{h}.$$ My confusion is that where I'd used the Jacobi identity, or is there any wrong with my deduction?@YCor

Comment: @一団和気  The Jacobi identity is what you wrote. It implies, for ideals $I,J,K$, that $[I,[J,K]]\subset [J,[K,I]]+[K,[I,J]]$ and this is how I used it.

Comment: @一団和気 the equalities in your comment are almost false.

Comment: So can I use Jacobi identity as $[\mathfrak{g},[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{h}]]\subset [\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]]+[\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{h},\mathfrak{g}]]=[\mathfrak{h},[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}]]$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.